# Dropzone previewsContainer initialization

Tags: dropzone.js

I'm using `Dropzone.autoDiscover = false` and I create my dropzones with `element.dropzone()`.
I want to display the processed files in another container, so I used `previewsContainer` attribute.
The files are appearing in that container but they're displaying badly, same as when dropzones are not properly initialized.
So my question is : is there a way to initialize the preview containers?

Thanks in advance,

Nenos

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To display properly the dropzone previews container must also have the `dropzone` class despite not being mentioned in the [documentation](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-previewsContainer).

So it should look like this:

html:

```
<div class="dropzone" id="myDropzone"></div>

<div class="dropzone-previews dropzone"></div>
```

js:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

$('#myDropzone').dropzone({
    previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",
    url: 'yoururl'
});
```