# Invalid previewsContainer in dropzonejs

Tags: jquery, html

I'm implementing dropzoneJS as per the following code. The drag and upload is fine and functional however I'm getting the following error message in dropzone.js

> Error: Invalid `previewsContainer` option provided. Please provide a CSS selector or a plain HTML element

How can I provide a selector for `previewscontainer`?

```js
Dropzone.options.singleupload = {
  paramName: "logo",
  maxFiles: 1,
  maxFilesize: 4,
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  acceptedFiles: 'image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif',
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.7.0/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>
<form class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="singleupload" action="upload.php">
  <div class="fallback">
    <input type="file" name="file" hidden />
  </div>
  <div class="dz-default dz-message">
    <span>drag here</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution by editing those two files

- dropzone.script.js
- dropzone.script.min.js
  where I commented this line

> **previewsContainer: "#button-select-upload",**

Comment: Instead of editing source file you should read how to use this plugin, there is an option https://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-previewsContainer or check similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46407983/dropzone-previewscontainer-initialization